# Banana Pi M2 Ultra no HDMI output

Tags: arm, debian, hdmi, banana-pi

I have Banana Pi M2 Ultra, I bought Samsung Micro SD Card (Class U1), uploaded image I downloaded from Allwinner's site, but I can't recieve HDMI output. I can connect to the board via SSH, and the system (debian) seems to be running fine, however there's no video output. Monitor is turning on every time I power up the board, but there is no image on both HDMI->HDMI and HDMI->DVI cables. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The state of the Linux kernel boot etc on these Chinese SBC boards are legendarily bad .. you will be using a very old v3.x kernel and if you are savvy with the old pre mainline kernel compilation - fex uboot kernel etc then its better just to compile the lot from scratch as so much isn't working properly in their images.

If not tech savvy then banana pi have several images setup for lcd's hdmi output etc ..

Hope it helps .. software lets down these SBC boards badly particularly with so much malware flying around